# How to bind data from mock.ts file to component?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I have a mock employee file and imported to employeelistcomponent. In the component I have defined a  property employee to bind the Employee Array from mock.ts. But its not working. No data is didplayed. What am I doing wrong?

**`component.ts`**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';
    import { EMPLOYEES } from '../mock-employees';
    import { Employee } from '../employee';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-employee-list',
    templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
    })
    export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
    employee = EMPLOYEES;
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() { }
    }
```

**`mock-employees.ts`**

```
    import { Employee } from './employee';
    export const EMPLOYEES: Employee[] = [
      { id:1, firstname: 'Hermoine', lastname: 'Granger', emailId: 
      'hgranger@myfirst.com', active: true },
      { id:2, firstname: 'Sirius', lastname: 'Black', emailId: 
      'sblack@myfirst.com', active: false },
      ];
```

**`component.html`**

```
        <ul>
        {{employee.id}}
        {{employee.firstname}}
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the reason is that employee is an array, not a single item. You will have to use *ngFor

So please change your HTML to:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let e of employee">
{{e.id}} - {{e.firstname}}
</li>
</ul>
```